# Dynamic module import doesn't work in python - why not?

Tags: python, python-import

I'm trying to dynamically import a python script `foo.py` into another executable script, which is in a deeply nested folder. I'm using

```
import os
sys.path.insert(0, '../../../../.') 
from foo import Bar
```

this works, and I can use `Bar` happily.

I would like to make the script dynamically determine the folder depth e.g.

```
import os
root_path = os.path.relpath(os.popen("git rev-parse --show-toplevel").read()).replace("../reponame", ".")
print(root_path) # prints '../../../../.'
sys.path.insert(0, root_path)
from foo import Bar
```

However this doesn't work, the script complains it can't find Bar when it is run.

Why is this?

Comment: what does `print(__file__)` say in both cases?

Comment: I think [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) tends to be more the standard way to do this?

Comment: Turn your relative path into an absolute path (`os.path.abspath()`) and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you debug you see `root_path` is actually `'../../../../.\n'`. Remove the `\n`

```
root_path.strip()
```